# Unable to edit TextBox in a UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, user-controls

I am working on a WPF application in which a user control is loaded over main window at run time.

I have a TextBox in the UserControl which is supposed to be a editable TextBox. But I am not able to edit it using keyboard input. Whereas, i am able to set the text pragmatically.

I have refered [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c1ebebbb-fca1-42da-89d9-b94a7980596e/set-keyboard-focus-to-usercontrol-chlid-from-xaml?forum=wpf) regarding the issue. Still i am not able to get through. My code is similar to one in the link above.

Please share your thoughts to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
         FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TestTxt}">

<Grid FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
        <TextBox x:Name="TestTxt" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain more. By "unable to type in" you mean it's disabled? Check the `IsEnable` property of the textbox.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Emad: its not disabled. It doesn't take keyboard input. I have made sure that the text box is enabled and 'IsReadOnly' is set to false.

Comment: One more thing that comes to my mind is that it's `Text` property is bound to another property which doesn't allow change. You need to post some code.

Comment: @Emad: I am not using 'Text' property anywhere in my code. Just for testing purpose i used that property.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code. Are you sure no input is getting inside textbox? Add event listeners for `TextChanged` and `KeyDown` place breakpoints and see if they hit.

Comment: Unable to get either of the events @Emad

Comment: They same link in bottom of the code they are given the text box focus in the user control load are you do the same ?

Comment: @Poovizhi Yes.. I did that too.

Answer (score 0):

In `UserControl_Loaded` add `TestTxt.Focus();`

Comment: Still facing the issue @swiszcz

Comment: Then you'll need to post a full example here. I've created a new WPF app project, I've added a user control with xaml copied from you, and after adding TestTxt.Focus() in UserControl_Loaded (and in MainWindow.xaml I've added FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TheNameOfUserControl}") on application start I could type into the textbox,

Comment: I found the root cause for this issue. This is a media streaming application. Because of video streaming, I am not able to update the UI. Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: This solves the issue, but if you have multiple text boxes then you are still not able to click and type on others, only the one that you made focused is able to be edited.